# Excel Power Pivot DAX calc column skips rows

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax

I have searched hi and low for the answer, but failing as it's hard to formulate.

I need to create a calculation that sums up sales for SKUs within a sub-brand

1. excluding the SKU in question
2. include other SKUs, as long as their first non-0 sales date is not closer than +/-3 time periods.

I created a calculated **column** .
The problem is that it calculates it only where sales for the specific SKU exist mutually.

```
Sub-brand total CALCULATED **COLUMN** DAX

=CALCULATE( 
 SUM([SKU SALES]) ,   
     FILTER( ALL(DATA), 
             Data[Sub-brand ID]=EARLIER(Data[Sub-brand ID]) && 
             Data[Time Period ID]=EARLIER(Data[Time Period ID]) && 
             ABS( Data[Launch Period ID]-EARLIER(Data[Launch Period ID]) ) >= 3
         ) 
    )
```

I feel that it's this line that's resonsible for it:

```
Data[Time Period ID]=EARLIER(Data[Time Period ID])
```

... as effectively if EARLIER(Data[Time Period ID]) doesn't exist, there is nothing to compare to. But if i take it out, it returns 1 number in every cell -  a total of SKU 1.

I also tried a measure. The below DAX achieved exact same result, but still not populating all dates where other SKUs are sold:

```
SUBBR TOTAL:=
     CALCULATE( [SKU SALES],  
                FILTER( ALLEXCEPT(Data, 
                        Data[Sub-brand ID],  
                        Data[Time Period ID] ),
                        ABS( Data[Launch Period ID]-MIN(Data[Launch Period ID])  ) >= 3
                          ) 
      )
```

It's almost like i need to run these calculations against the distinct list of dates rather than where SKUs sales exist..

Please refer to pic attached showing data sample, DAX and achieved-desired output. i dont know how to attach a sample file but i made effort to ensure example is descriptive (hopefully).

Thank you in advance,
Lana

[image: SAMPLE AND RESULTS]

Comment: In the screenshot you state, _it should include all SKU's except the one for it is calculated for_ however when there is no a SKU in earlier/later for that Time Period it should take the current SKU sales values. Could you explain in detail?

Comment: Hi @alejandrozuleta, basically, if you look at the last 2 columns - that's what i need. I.e. SKU 2's sub-brand total should have been equal to SKU 1, and for SKU 1 it would be SKU 2. The problem is that because SKU 2 didn't have any data for periods before 8, the formula doesn't calculate anything (red-font cells in the last column shows what's missing) . Does it make it clearer? I think i'm asking for too much...